# CAML query using a Choice field is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query, caml, camlviewfields

I have the following CAML query inside our SharePoint online site collection, to get all the list items which have a choice field named `CustomerOrderAlert` = `No`, as follow:-

```
                List customerliveorderlist = omsWeb.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/CustomerLiveOrder/");
                CamlQuery query1 = new CamlQuery();
                query1.ViewXml = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='CustomerOrderAlert'/><Value Type='Choice'>No</Value></Eq></Where>";
                ListItemCollection c = customerliveorderlist.GetItems(query1);

                     context.Load(c,
                           items => items.Include(
                           item => item["OrderLiveDeliveredDate"],
                           item => item.Id,
                ));
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

but i am getting all the items even the ones which have their `CustomerOrderAlert` = `Yes`? any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add View and Query element to your query. Try below

```
query1.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='CustomerOrderAlert'/><Value Type='Choice'>No</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: worked well thanks